# Cross browser supported curved table corner CSS attribute

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Is there a cross browser CSS attribute for curved corners on HTML tables?

Something like:

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

Every example I've found online resembles the follwoing:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
```

Which I don't think is cross browser...

Comment: Can u please tell me more specific?

Comment: use csspie http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Actually, I think figured this jsfiddle covers it:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eYg78/

Comment: `border-radius` has been widely supported for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS>>>>

```
 .round {
 /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 

 /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
 -moz-border-radius: 12px; 

 /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
 border-radius: 12px; 
 }
```

And this website really helps you in this situation: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/